# jsf not showing the fields just the text

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, facelets

My jsf page on IE won't show anything on firefox i atleast get the text. Strange thing is that there is no error so i am not sure what is wrong. I looked around for information and even added a f:view for the page but still nothing. Thank you for your time.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
                  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" >
            <f:view contentType="text/html">

            <h:head>
            <title>QC-Form</title>
            <link href="./css/styles.css" 
                  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            </h:head>



            <h:body>
            <h1 class="title">QC Form</h1>
            <br/> <br/>

              <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
              <p><b>Enter the information below: </b> </p>
              </font>

            <h:form>

             <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 

             <h:panelGroup id="initialInfo">

                <b>Your initials: </b>  
                    <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.techNameValue}"/><br/>
                <br/>

                <b>Model #: </b>  
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.modelValue}">
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="3600" itemLabel="3600" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="7200" itemLabel="7200" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="8300" itemLabel="8300" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="8400" itemLabel="8400" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="8500p" itemLabel="8500p" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="8800" itemLabel="8800" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="9000" itemLabel="9000" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="9008" itemLabel="9008" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="9200" itemLabel="9200" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="9300" itemLabel="9300" />
                </h:selectOneMenu><br/>
                 <br/>

                <b>Date : </b>
                 <h:outputText  value="#{currentDate}"/>
                <br/> <br/>


                <b>Serial #: </b>  
                    <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.serialValue}"/><br/>
                <br/>

                <b>Customer Name: </b>  
                    <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.customerNameValue}"/><br/>
                <br/>

                <b>Special Instructions: </b>  
                    <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.specialInstructionsValue}"/><br/>    

             </h:panelGroup>
            </font>

              <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
              <p><b>QC Process</b> </p>
              </font>

             <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 

            <h:panelGroup id="dliSerial">
             <b>1.Unit Serial number has been applied: </b>
             <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.unitSerialValue}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{qcFormBean.valueQcValue}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br/>

            </h:panelGroup>

            <br/>
            <b>2.Screen Protector has been applied: </b>
            <h:panelGroup id="dliSticker">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dliStickerValue}">
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
                  <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker"  limitRender="true" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup id="perfbyDlitcSticker">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.stickerFreq}"
                rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>


            <br/>
            </font>

            <h:commandButton action="#{qcFormBean.submitForm()}"/>

            </h:form>

            </h:body>

            </f:view>

            </html>
```

Update: Right clicking on the source file on firefox does show the raw code being displayed like this:

```
<b>Your initials: </b>  
    <h:inputText value=""></h:inputText><br />
<br />

<b>Model #: </b>  
<h:selectOneMenu value="">
</h:selectOneMenu><br />
 <br />
```

and my web.xml file has the following servlet information.

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source*. Do you still see raw XHTML source code or do you see the JSF-generated HTML output? Symptoms indicate the former, but it's a bit surprising that you didn't seem to bother to check what exactly the webbrowser actually retrieved.

Comment: By the way, the HTML `<font>` tag is deprecated since 1998. Make sure you're reading up to date HTML tutorials.

Comment: Will remove the font tags now, btw when i see the source i do seem to be getting the raw code. Firefox retrived the text outside the tags and while it shows in the source code the "/h:inputText" and all that still nothing will update my question

Comment: Look, there's the cause. The HTTP request didn't invoke the `FacesServlet` at all and hence it wasn't able to parse the XHTML source code and produce the desired HTML output. You surely know that browsers don't understand XHTML/PHP/JSF/ASP/JSP/Python/whatever, but only HTML, right?

Comment: Then the web.xml file is to blame for this is what your saying?

Comment: Or is the tag " f:view contentType="text/html" " incorrect?

Comment: or is there another reason why the The HTTP request didn't invoke the FacesServlet ?

Comment: You have mapped the `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `*.jsf`. So it's logically only invoked on URLs matching `*.jsf`. If the request URL (as you see in browser's address bar) doesn't match that, then, well, it won't be invoked. Taking a JSF pause and learning basic Servlet API would do you much good.

Comment: I am just wondering wth happened, I didn't have this issue before on my last jsf project before you told me to start a new one. And the page was atleast showing and the page does show a .jsf on the link. Guess i need to really look in my web.xml file. And i thought i was suppose to save it as a xhtml file and not a jsf file.

Comment: Another possible cause would be that you aren't running JSF 2.2 at all. The `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace is introduced since JSF 2.2 and won't work if you're using an older JSF version. However, those `<f:xxx>` and `<a4j:xxx>` tags should be successfully parsed, but you didn't explicitly mention that.

Comment: This ain't 2.2 jsf its just 2.0 JSF.

Comment: Well, then there's another possible cause, provided that `<f:xxx>` and `<a4j:xxx>` tags *are* successfully parsed.

Comment: I think i see something the f:xxx isn't being parsed or shown in the raw xhtml source code only the h:xxx and the a4j:xxx what does this mean I am not getting any errors at all though.

Comment: Eh? Wait, what? You don't have `<f:xxx>` and `<a4j:xxx>` in XHTML source code? In the XHTML source code in your question you've actually a `<f:view>` and a couple of `<f:selectItem>`s! Or are you now confusing the raw XHTML source code as you can find in Java EE web project folder with the parsed and generated HTML output as you see in browser's *View Source*?

Comment: I guess the second one as on the web browser it doesn't show the f:view and the f:selectitem. I do notice that difference between what the raw xhtml source code see's on the web browser and what is actually in eclipse.

Comment: Well, then it's most definitely that cause.

Comment: so the xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" is the culprit. should I use something else for f besides this then? What would you recommend?

Comment: Eh? It's the other way round .. You missed my answer?

Comment: Sorry I did miss your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the symptoms described in the comments, the `<f:xxx>` and `<a4j:xxx>` tags are properly processed by JSF, but the `<h:xxx>` tags not. Now, let's look at their XML namespace declarations, which is where all the processing starts:

```
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" >
```

The `xmlns.jcp.org` domain as you've declared for the `<h:xxx>` XML namespace is introduced since JSF 2.2. The symptom of it being unprocessed thus indicates that you aren't running JSF 2.2 at all, but an older JSF 2.x version, such as 2.0 or 2.1, which don't recognize the new XML namespace domains yet.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Either fix the `<h:xxx>` XML namespace accordingly to match JSF 2.0/2.1 specification:

   ```
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   ```
2. Or, just upgrade to JSF 2.2.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC , sorry it took awhile I would of never seen or know that issue, I just changed my xml namespace to keep it simple thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That means your jsf tags are not parsed to plain html. To confirm this one see the page view source if you could see the plain jsf tags then that is the problem.

The primary reason for tags not being parsed means your request is not being handed by Faces servlet. You should have some thing like this in your web.xml

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>         
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>    
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I have instead something like this:
' <servlet> 
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
' 
I am guessing this isn't correct?